# join dictionaries in single data frame on a common key

Tags: python, pandas

```
d1 = [{'x':'a','y':0.5}, {'x':'b', 'y':3.0}]
d2 = [{'x':'a','w':1.0}, {'x':'b', 'w':1.0,'z':1.5}]
```

I'd like to "join" these dictionaries in a data frame on the common key `x`

```
   x    y    w    z
0  a  0.5  1.0  NaN
1  b  3.0  1.0  1.5
```

I tried

```
d3 = d1 + d2
pd.DataFrame(d3)

   x    y    w    z
0  a  0.5  NaN  NaN
1  b  3.0  NaN  NaN
2  a  NaN  1.0  NaN
3  b  NaN  1.0  1.5
```

Then I thought of merging the dictionaries first

```
d3 = {**d1, **d2}
```

but this won't work because the dictionaries are enclosed inside lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `merge`:

```
pd.merge(*[pd.DataFrame(d) for d in [d1,d2]], 
         on='x')
```

Output:

```
   x    y    w    z
0  a  0.5  1.0  NaN
1  b  3.0  1.0  1.5
```

Or you can also go with your route and groupby:

```
pd.DataFrame(d1+d2).groupby('x', as_index=False).first()
```

Comment: Assuming `x` is the only key in common, `pd.merge(*map(pd.DataFrame, (d1, d2)))`

Answer (score 2):

#### `toolz.dicttoolz.merge`

This is a pure python/dictionary merge.
The first thing I'll do is to rearrange the list of dictionaries such that I have a hashable key, namely `x`.

```
d1_ = {d['x']:d for d in d1}
d2_ = {d['x']:d for d in d2}
```

This assumes there are no repeated dictionaries with the same `x` values in any one list.  This allows me to leverage dictionary lookup speeds.

Now I'll use `toolz.dicttoolz.merge`

```
from toolz.dicttoolz import merge

d1_ = {d['x']:d for d in d1}
d2_ = {d['x']:d for d in d2}
[merge(d, d2_[x]) for x, d in d1_.items()]

[{'x': 'a', 'y': 0.5, 'w': 1.0}, {'x': 'b', 'y': 3.0, 'w': 1.0, 'z': 1.5}]
```

We can see this does what we want more clearly if we drop it into a dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame([merge(d, d2_[x]) for x, d in d1_.items()])

   x    y    w    z
0  a  0.5  1.0  NaN
1  b  3.0  1.0  1.5
```

Getting a little more "out there".  We can use both `merge` and `merge_with`.  `merge_with` let's us specify **how** to merge.

```
from toolz.dicttoolz import merge, merge_with

merge_with(merge, {d['x']: d for d in d1}, {d['x']: d for d in d2})

{'a': {'x': 'a', 'y': 0.5, 'w': 1.0},
 'b': {'x': 'b', 'y': 3.0, 'w': 1.0, 'z': 1.5}}
```

Or we can make a more general purpose helper function

```
from toolz.dicttoolz import merge, merge_with

def get_xify(char):
    def xify(list_of_dicts):
        return {d[char]: d for d in list_of_dicts if char in d}
    return xify

def merge_list_of_dicts_on(list_of_dicts, on):
    return list(merge_with(merge, *map(get_xify(on), [d1, d2])).values())

merge_list_of_dicts_on([d1, d2], 'x')

[{'x': 'a', 'y': 0.5, 'w': 1.0}, {'x': 'b', 'y': 3.0, 'w': 1.0, 'z': 1.5}]
```